# div stick to a position:fixed link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a jQuery code to track the position of a link (`position:fixed`) then use it as the position of a DIV (that sit just below it). So when a user scrolls, the link which is fixed (`top:0; left:0; right:0;`) will automatically sticks to the top, my jQuery code enable the `div` to follow the link when it moves , BUT it's laggy.

```
<a href="link" id="link" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;">Link</a>
<div id="divsticktolink" style="width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;">Test</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  var link = $("#link");  
  var position = link.offset();
  var top = position.top + 10;
     $('#divsticktolink').css('left' , position.left + 'px');
     $('#divsticktolink').css('top' , top + 'px');
});
```

How can I solve the laggy part?

P/S: I know I can archive smooth one by placing them both in a `div` which is `position:fixed` but I wanna try out this technique.

Comment: It won't get smoothier, the best you can do is `animate()` instead of immediately setting the position.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve the lag but you can make it more efficient by combining these two lines...

```
 $('#divsticktolink').css('left' , position.left + 'px');
 $('#divsticktolink').css('top' , top + 'px');
```

into this...

```
 $('#divsticktolink').css({
                            'left' : position.left + 'px',
                            'top' : top + 'px'
 });
```

The `var` declaration can be combined too, but it may not make much of an impact...

```
var link = $("#link"),  
    position = link.offset(),
    top = position.top + 10;
```